# Getting a Mass Asssignment Error using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe payments in my rails app. I'm pretty much following the tutorial in the railscasts and just customizing it, but I seem to be getting stuck with mass assignment errors related to the stripe_card_token. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's a bunch of my code http://pastie.org/4191557

Comment: Which errors are you talking about? I've pasted the logged ones in the pastie

Answer (score 0):

In your Stripe_token migration, field name is :stripe_customer_token and you have written :stripe_card_token

Generally,
Cannot mass-assign' means you cannot assign a value automatically like this:
@idea.pledges.create(params[:pledge])

Either use
attr_accessible :stripe_customer_token

OR

Directly assign value

@idea.pledges.stripe_customer_token = params[:pledge][:stripe_customer_token]

Comment: Yeah although in the tutorials it looks like the stripe_card_token is temporary, so its supposed to get converted into the stripe_customer_token and stored for later use. I'll try to directly assign the value, but would that be insecure?